# What's the file path in Linux

Tags: java

I need a java program to get the path of a certain file.(in Linux)

it should look like this

```
    FileInputStream svconfig = new FileInputStream(
            "filepathinlinux");
```

Comment: It's whatever path the file has. If this is some special file you have to tell us.

Comment: so we should just guess at what your directory/filename structure is? I'll go with `/foo/bar/baz/argle/bargle/cutekittens/whatever.txt`

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: i'm new to linux and i don't know where to get the filepath similar to then one in Windows(Ex:C:MyDocumets)

Comment: A complete path in linux looks like this `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` . A relative path looks like `../tests` .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
System.out.println("Path : " + svconfig.getAbsolutePath());
```